# Add attribute disable to input text with Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

How to add attribute disable to an input text with Selenium Python?

```
<div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="true"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="true" disabled = "true"></div>
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't do this (or edit the page in any way) with Selenium. You should strive to interact with the page as a user would. What action would the user take on the page that would cause this INPUT to be disabled? Write code to do that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `execute_script` something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".selectable-text")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('disabled','true')", element)
```

Hope this helps you!